# Java Menu Interface Student System

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a  Student database system, but I'm struggling with the interface menu, When I press 1 for option 1 nothing happens and theres many other errors like it wont print. What am I doing wrong?

Heres the code for RegistryInterface:

```
package student;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RegistryInterface
{

    private Registry theRegistry = null;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public RegistryInterface(Registry theRegistry)
    {
    }

    public void doMenu()
    {
        String decission;

        System.out.println("Registry Main Menu\n*******************\n");
        System.out.println("1. Add a Student \n2. Delete a Student"
                + "\n3. Print Registry\n4. Quit");

        System.out.println("Select Option [1, 2, 3, 4] :>");
        decission = input.nextLine();

        while (decission != "4")
        {
            if ("1".equals(decission))
            {
                doAddStudent();
            }

            if ("2".equals(decission))
            {
                doDeleteStudent();
            }


            if ("3".equals(decission))
            {
                doPrintRegistry();
                break;
            }

            if ("4".equals(decission))
            {

                System.out.println(" System Closing Down.........");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void doAddStudent()
    {
        String addMore = null;

        String foreName;
        String surName;
        int iDNumber;

        while ("y".equals(addMore))
        {
            System.out.println("Add New Student\n***********\n");

            System.out.println("Enter forename       :>");
            foreName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\nEnter surname      :>");
            surName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter ID for Student :>");
            iDNumber = input.nextInt();

            theRegistry.addStudent(new Student(surName, foreName, iDNumber));

            System.out.println("Add Another Student(Y/N) :>");
            addMore = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    private void doDeleteStudent()
    {
        int studID;
        String another = null;

        System.out.println("Add New Student\n***********\n");

        while("y".equals(another))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Student ID To Delete :>");
            studID = input.nextInt();

            theRegistry.deleteStudent(studID);

            System.out.println("\nDelete Another? (Y/N)");
            another = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    private void doPrintRegistry()
    {
        System.out.println("Printing Registry\n***********\n");
        theRegistry.format();
    }
}
```

And heres the code for registryApp:

```
public class RegistryApp
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Registry theRegistry = new Registry();

        RegistryInterface aRegInterface = new RegistryInterface(theRegistry);

        aRegInterface.doMenu();

    }
}
```

And my register class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Registry
{
    public LinkedList<Student> studentList = new LinkedList<>();
    public Iterator<Student> iter = studentList.iterator();

    public Registry()
    {
    }

    public void addStudent(Student aStudent)
    {
        Iterator<Student> addIterator = studentList.iterator();

        while (addIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = addIterator.next();
            if (ob.getStudentID() == aStudent.getStudentID())
            {
                System.out.println("This Student ID "+ aStudent.getStudentID()+ " Is Already Used");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student "+ aStudent.getForeName() + " "
                + "" + aStudent.getForeName() +" "
                + "Successfully Added To System.....\n");

        studentList.addLast(aStudent);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(int studentID)
    {
        Iterator<Student> deleteIterator = studentList.iterator();
        boolean removed = false;

        while(deleteIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = deleteIterator.next();

            if(ob.getStudentID() == studentID)
            {
                deleteIterator.remove();
                removed = true;
                System.out.println(ob.getForeName() + " " + ob.getSurName() + " Was Succesffully Removed from System. \n");
            }
        }
        if(!removed)
        {
            System.out.println("Student ID not found");
        }
    }

    public String format()
    {
        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Student> formatIterator = studentList.iterator();

        while(formatIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = formatIterator.next();
            sB.append(ob.format());      
        }
        return sB.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        Iterator<Student> toStringIterator = studentList.iterator();
        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();

        while(toStringIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Student ob = toStringIterator.next();
            sB.append(ob.toString()).append("\n");
        }
        return sB.toString();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside this loop...

```
while (decission != "4")
```

... you never set a new value to `decission`. So, the loop will either run infinitely, or do nothing.

Also, the string you scan from input will always be a newly created string, so it will always be != "4" even if you typed "4".

Comment: I dont understand sorry, What am i ment to do with the loop like?

Comment: A loop will keep running its body over and over, checking the condition every time, until the condition is false. If nothing inside the loop can make the condition false, you have an "infinite loop".